# Horizontal alignment in multirow table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

I have this table to which I want the first column to be horizontaly centered and the cells:

- "annotated messages"
- "annotated process"
- "provided guidelines"
- "annotator agreement"

having two lines, but I'm having problems with it.

I'm new to tables in latex...

Also, I don't know why the tables is not centered...

[image]

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Paper}}  & \textbf{\cite{Davidson2017}} & \textbf{\cite{Nobata2017}} & \textbf{\cite{Zhang17}} &  \textbf{\cite{Warner}} & \textbf{\cite{Kwok2013}}\\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Collection}} &  Twitter search engine with words present in Hatebase.org. lexicon. & Comments posted on Yahoo! Finance and News. & Twitter seach engine about refugees and Muslims & Yahoo! News and offensive websites id by AJC. & Twitter accounts known to be racist.\\
    \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Annotated messages}} & 25.000 tweets & 2.000 comments & 2.435 tweets & 1.000 paragraphs & 24.582 tweets\\
    \hline 
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Annotation Process}} & At least three CrowdFlower workers. & Mechanical Turk experiment. & unanimous agreement between two researchers & Three annotators & annotated by authors \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Provided Guidelines}} & yes & yes & no & no & no\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Annotator Agreement}} & Inter-coder agreement of 92\% & Fleiss's Kappa of 0.401 & unanimous agreement & Fleiss's Kappa of 0.63 & -\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \smallskip
    \caption{Dataset annotation process used in other studies}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I've removed the `align` tag.  `align` refers explicitly to a multi-line math display environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `multirow` for this table: just use `tabularx`, redefining the `X` column type as `X{#1}`.

Unrelated: you should avoid using the `H` placement letter – it often leads to large blank spaces in pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, float}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}X|*{5}{X|}}
    \hline
    Paper & \textbf{\cite{Davidson2017}} & \textbf{\cite{Nobata2017}} & \textbf{\cite{Zhang17}} & \textbf{\cite{Warner}} & \textbf{\cite{Kwok2013}}\\
    \hline
    Collection & Twitter search engine with words present in Hatebase.org. lexicon. & Comments posted on Yahoo! Finance and News. & Twitter seach engine about refugees and Muslims & Yahoo! News and offensive websites id by AJC. & Twitter accounts known to be racist.\\
    \hline
   Annotated messages & 25.000 tweets & 2.000 comments & 2.435 tweets & 1.000 paragraphs & 24.582 tweets\\
    \hline
    Annotation Process & At least three CrowdFlower workers. & Mechanical Turk experiment. & unanimous agreement between two researchers & Three annotators & annotated by authors \\
    \hline
    Provided Guidelines & yes & yes & no & no & no\\
    \hline
   Annotator Agreement & Inter-coder agreement of 92\% & Fleiss's Kappa of 0.401 & unanimous agreement & Fleiss's Kappa of 0.63 & – \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \smallskip
    \caption{Dataset annotation process used in other studies}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks, problem solved.

Comment: One more thing, how can I add some width to a certain column with this type of configuration?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *adding width* to  a column?

Comment: For example if I wanted to have the second column with a exact width.

Comment: Suppose you want to have a 3 cm wide second column. Just use this preamble for the table: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}X|>{\centering}m{3cm}*{4}{X|}}`. The only condition for `tabularx` to work properly is that it has at least one `X` column.

Comment: Thanks! @Bernard